# Is there a environment variable that I can tell what Pivotal Cloud Foundry Foundation I am running on?

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

Is there a environment variable that I can tell what Pivotal Cloud Foundry Foundation I am running on? I found CF_INSTANCE_INDEX that tells me which instance I am running on, but I am also looking for something to tell me which Foundation I am on.  I ask because I have two foundations setup in active passive, I have a use case that I need to know which foundation I am running on.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if below JSON of PCF helps in extracting what you are looking for -

```
"application_env_json": {
"VCAP_APPLICATION": {
  "cf_api": "https://abc.xyz.net",
  "limits": {
    "fds": 16384
  },
  "application_name": "My-SimpleApp",
  "application_uris": [
    "My-SimpleApp.abc.xyz.net"
  ],
  "name": "My-SimpleApp",
  "space_name": "MY_SPACE",
  "space_id": "6e84e9d5-ed09-42a8-9309-12345",
  "uris": [
    "My-SimpleApp.abc.xyz.net"
  ],
  "users": null,
  "application_id": "8b891e55-0661-4c70-b2d9-345edf"
}
```

}

it should be something like this on Env variable - `"VCAP_APPLICATION.space_name"`

I haven't tried this but was getting the service variable in this way

Comment: Hello, space_name is the name of a specific environment within a PCF Foundation, I have multiple PCF foundations, I think I can get what I need from the CF_API link.

Comment: My intention was to give you hint - Here is the detailed description of PCF env variables - https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html

Comment: Thank you for the info!

Comment: `cf_api` is probably the closest thing in VCAP_APPLICATION, it would tell you the API URL of your foundation. You'd have to be able to translate that to the environment name on your own or perhaps send an HTTP request to `cf_api/v2/info` and get info for that environment. All in all, if you really need this why not just set an env variable when you deploy? `FOUNDATION=xyz` or have your platform operator set a running environment variable `FOUNDATION=xzy` which would apply to all apps.